# Attach my countdown to dragable element

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, countdown

I have this script and would like the dragable area not to be active until the start button has been pressed. When the start button has been pressed, the "game" begins and one can start drag items into the bucket. Anyone has a clue on how I can do this?

I have tried many different things, but bugs keep appearing all the way.

Here is my code (kind of an ugly playground for now). :)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".items img").draggable({
            revert: true,

        });
        $("#cart").droppable({
            accept: '.items img',
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#update').show();
                prod_id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index2.php",
                    data: "id=" + prod_id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $('#update').hide();
                        $('#cart').html(html);
                        $("#cart img").draggable({revert: true});
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $("#trash").droppable({
            accept: '#cart img',
            hoverClass: 'trashhover',
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                prod_id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                ui.draggable.remove();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index2.php",
                    data: "id=" + prod_id,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $('#cart').html(html);
                        $("#cart img").draggable();
                    }
                });
            }
    });
});
</script>

        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="center">
<ul class="items">
    <li><img src="images/beer.jpg" id="Ol" width="100" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/lotion.jpg" id="Solkrem" width="100" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/melon.jpg" id="Melon" width="100" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/shorts.jpg" id="Shorts" width="100" /></li>
</ul>
<div id="cartdiv">
    <div id="cart">
        Du har ikke startet spillet
    </div>
    <div id="update">
        Oppdaterer <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
    <p class="countdown" style="clear:both; display:block; height:50px;"></p>
</div>
<div id="trash" >
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="countdown2"></div>
<input type="button" value="reset" id="reset" />
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    var interval;
    var minutes = 0;
    var seconds = 10;

    function countdown2(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    alert(el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!");                    
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 10;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
reset.onclick = function() {
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 10;
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
    window.location.href = 'logout.php';
}
var start = document.getElementById('start');

start.onclick = function() {
    if (!interval) {
        countdown2('countdown2');
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: can u simulate the same on jsfiddle

Comment: Does this help? :) http://jsfiddle.net/Tq5Ug/
When it says "Oppdaterer" at the bottom, the image has been dragged successfully and handled by db, etc. Try press start, to activate my countdown.

Comment: this is what you wanted right ? http://jsfiddle.net/Tq5Ug/1/

Comment: I thank you a lot my friend :] Exactly what I was looking for. Have a nice day!

Comment: your welcome buddy, just tick it as answer, this would reduce the no of open questions from the queue. Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to disable(on page load) the **droppable**  on **#Cart** element and then enable it on click event of the **start** button .

```
 start.onclick = function() {
   $( "#cart" ).droppable( "option", "disabled", false );
     if (!interval) {
       countdown2('countdown2');
     }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tq5Ug/1/

Happy Coding :)